# How to get dynamic data into textbox in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, autocomplete

Actually in my Flex Application i'm getting values from Database and Stored into a ArrayCollection...
    [Bindable]public var data : ArrayCollection;
 ....
....

```
Actually ArrayCollection data contain values like...java,flex,dotnet,php.....
```

So now i'm adding this ArrayCollection into textbox for getting Dynamic value just like Auto-Suggestion

but it is giving all data once but i want when we type 'J' dynamically 'J' related words will be display....

Please help me....

Comment: @www.flextras.com This one's for you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of component you're looking for is called AutoComplete.  There are quite a few implementations out there, but my favorite is the [Flextras AutoCompleteComboBox](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductHome&productID=19), because I built it.  It is available free for production use; but you'll have to register to download the SWC.